# Passing UUID of one table to another table as a Foreign key value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, uuid

I have table `Employee` in Postgres:

```
drop table if exists employee; 
create table employee ( 
 id uuid default uuid_generate_v4 () primary key, 
 first_name varchar not null, 
 last_name varchar not null
 );
```

And another table `salary` :

```
drop table if exists salary; 
create table salary ( 
 check_id uuid default uuid_generate_v4 () primary key,  
 salary int not null, 
 employee_id uuid  references employee (id) 
);
```

`employee_id` is the foreign key to `id` in the Employee table, but I don't understand how to insert a value inside `employee_id` since UUID is unique.

I am inserting values into `Employee` table:

```
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, email, code) values ( 'jonh', 'smith', 'jonh@example.com', '1');
```

And then if I try insert values into `salary` table:

```
insert into salary (salary ) values ('1000');
```

Then `select` command will return `employee_id` value empty.

But if I make it `default uuid_generate_v4 ()`, then result is: `Key (employee_id)=(c4ccd745-02ba-4a0e-8586-32e3c6a2b84a) is not present in table "employee".`

I understand that because `employee_id` is a foreign key it should match with uuid in `employee`, but since uuid is mostly unique, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `uuid` that was inserted into the `employee` table. You can do this with a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) in a single statement:

```
WITH new_employee AS (
    INSERT INTO employee (first_name, last_name, email, code)
    VALUES ('jonh', 'smith', 'jonh@example.com', '1')
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO salary (salary, employee_id)
    SELECT 1000, id
    FROM new_employee;
```

Comment: Hi Loressa, if the answer solves your issue you should accept it as the correct answer. That way other SO users will know that the question has been correctly answered